# AWS Lambda and SES - send personal email to multiple users [30 sec lambda limitation problem]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I'm using AWS lambda to build my web app (next.js) and I'm successfully sending email using AWS SES.
I set a CloudWatch event to run every day, that runs a lambda function that sends personal email to some of the users.
The problem is that lambda has running time limit of max 30sec so I can't use it to send emails to a lot of users.

What can I do to solve this issue?
After looking in the CloudWatch logs, I saw it took ~5sec to complete this lambda for ONE user.
So, I'm guessing it will not handle 100 users or more.

Comment: You can now configure your AWS Lambda functions to run up to 15 minutes per execution. However, i would take a look at your code to figure out why it takes 5 seconds to send email to one recipient

Answer (score 0):

At first, it is strange that sending an email takes 5 seconds unless there is a heavy data preparation to format each email.

As for the lambda timeout, to have a scalable design, I recommend that you make lambda A --> SQS ---> lambda B.

Lambda A just writes messages to sqs (recipient's email, template name, whatever necessary info to format the email). Please note that you can write a batch of messages (10 messages) to SQS.. based on one of my previous implementations, it is easy to write 5000+ sqs messages in 30 sec. You can set a longer time up to 15 minutes if lambda is not behind an API.

lambda B will be triggered by SQS to format the email and send it to SES. You can set batch size and sqs config the best suits your design and quota. This way, you can always send emails regardless of the volume as long as quotas of AWS Account allows. Please note that you can also introduce a random delay to each message written to SQS to make sure the limit of SES is not violated (14/sec <== can be raised easily).

you may consider a better design too based on your app architecture :)

Comment: Thanks! good idea. "up to 15 minutes if lambda is not behind an API" - what do you mean here? I remember i saw a 30 sec limitation and now i found a page that says 15min. "14/sec <== can be raised easily" - Do you mean I can raise this limit to more than 14/sec easily? And If I violate this limit of SES, it just drops the emails or put in the queue?

Comment: "up to 15 minutes if lambda is not behind an API" << I mean if Lambda is invoked by API Gateway. "14/sec <== can be raised easily"  << by raising a request to AWS to increase it. This is a soft limit.